# Conditions in Mysql query does not work

Tags: php, mysql

I have problems while creating a query for my Live search engine.

The structure of the table is like:

```
           street   | zipcode | city

col1.:  streetname  | 12345   | london
col1.:  otherstreet | 12345   | london
```

My problem is the following:

When I will search for `12345 london streetname` I will get a wrong result for the queries that are quiet simple. When i will echo out the query I get this as a result:

```
`zipcode` LIKE '12345%' AND `city` LIKE 'london%' OR `street` LIKE 'london%' AND `city` LIKE 'streetname%' OR `street` LIKE 'streetname%'
```

I fetch the results by using:

```
$where = ...

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE $where");
$result = $query->num_rows;
    if ($result !== 0 ){
        echo $result;

        while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo 
                $row["zipcode"], 
                ' ', 
                $row["city"]';

        }

    }
```

and the curious about that is that I receive a correct result when I change the order of input into:

`streetname 12345 london`

then I get:

```
`city` LIKE 'streetname%' OR `street` LIKE 'streetname%' AND `city` LIKE 'london%' OR `street` LIKE 'london%' AND `zipcode` LIKE '12345%'
```

it seems like there is also a problem with the last `AND`condition. When I will change the zipcode in that example:

`streetname london 12345`

it does not matter and even with wrong zipcode I get this result.

So if someone can give me hints to solve this issue I really would apreciate.

Thanks alot.

Comment: 1) Operator precedence 2) Parenthesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND` has tighter binding precedence than `OR`, so your first expression is treated as:

```
(`zipcode` LIKE '12345%' AND `city` LIKE 'london%')
OR (`street` LIKE 'london%' AND `city` LIKE 'streetname%')
OR (`street` LIKE 'streetname%')
```

The second one is parsed as:

```
(`city` LIKE 'streetname%')
OR (`Strasse` LIKE 'streetname%' AND `city` LIKE 'london%')
OR (`street` LIKE 'london%' AND `zipcode` LIKE '12345%')
```

You need to use explicit parentheses to specify the way you actually want the conditions to be combined.

Answer (score 0):

You have to isolate their questinonamentos in select ...

try

(`zipcode` LIKE '12345%' AND `city` LIKE 'london%') OR (`street` LIKE 'london%' AND `city` LIKE 'streetname%') OR (`street` LIKE 'streetname%')

Answer (score 0):

Use parentesis to group conditions, like this:

```
(`zipcode` LIKE '12345%' AND `city` LIKE 'london%') OR (`street` LIKE 'london%' AND `city` LIKE 'streetname%') OR `street` LIKE 'streetname%'
```